# How view 1000 line when use command on linux

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

Example command:

```
$ locate .conf
$ ls
```

if it shows 1000 lines, how can I view all lines? In terminal, there's a restriction for xx line (I don't know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the output to a pager like `more` or `less`.

```
$ locate .conf | less
```

For more complex output I also like to pipe into `vim`.

```
$ g++ -E something.cpp | vi -
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the long command through "less":

```
ls | less
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to `less` and `vim` usage which is the most common case here you can also increase the buffer size of your terminal, if you are using `gonme-terminal` edit the profile used and set the desired number of lines.

[image]